# cache image address in ajax load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, caching

I am creating an ajax slider to show images. It works perfectly but problem is image cache. when images change, because this is an ajax load, there is no cache here and image is displayed with delay. How can i display images without any delay? here is my code:

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var auto = setInterval(function(){
            $("#test").load("ajax.php", {count : count}, function(){
                count = count + 1;
                if (count == 5) {
                    count = 0;
                }
            }).fadeOut(100).fadeIn(100);
        },3000);
```

PHP in ajax.php:

```
<?php   
    $pathArray = array( "<img src='pic/85.jpg' width='128' height='169'>",
                        "<img src='pic/18.jpg' width='128' height='169'>",
                        "<img src='pic/7.jpg' width='128' height='169'>",
                        "<img src='pic/004.jpg' width='128' height='169'>",
                        "<img src='pic/26.jpg' width='128' height='169'>"
);

    if (isset($_POST["count"])) {
        echo $pathArray[intval($_POST["count"])];
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You browser should be auto caching images path regardless of where the text is coming from, either its hard coded, java script ajax or any other, unless you specified otherwise.

If anything is slow, it seems to be your network...

You could always create a javascript array and save the path to the image if it's been called before using that count.

```
if (typeof images[count] != 'undefined') {
  // call ajax and save the path here, 
} else {
  //  display image
}
```